# Publish WinForms application on remote server

Tags: winforms, iis-7.5

I want to publish my WinForms Application on remote server to enable web installation for the application. 
I need some relevant information how to configure IIS 7.5 web site to enable publishing by VS2012. I've found some links but it mostly about publishing web application and as I could understand the process is different in some points.
Where I could find information for the configuring IIS web site?

Comment: You can't put a WinForms application on a website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a ClickOnce application?

If this is the case, you simply need to have write access to where it is going to be deployed, and users need read access.

Comment: Thank you for reply! 
I suggested it. But I still cannot understand how I should configure my site to set writable access for developer and readable acces for users.